# Exporting to CSV File

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export the results of this code to a CSV file.  I copied 2 of the results further down below after the code.  There are 14 items for each stock and I'd like to write to a CSV file and have a column for each of the 14 items and one row for each stock.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,25,63,64,65,66,67'
html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'screener-content'})
table = main_div.find('table')
sub = table.findAll('tr')
rows = sub[5].findAll('td')
for row in rows:
    link = row.a
    if link is not None:
        print(link.get_text())
```

This is the format of the results, 14 items/columns for each stock.

```
PTN
Palatin Technologies, Inc.
Healthcare
Diagnostic Substances
USA
240.46M
9.22
193.43M
2.23M
0.76
1.19
7.21%
1,703,285
3
LKM
Link Motion Inc.
Technology
Application Software
China
128.95M
-
50.40M
616.76K
1.73
1.30
16.07%
1,068,798
4
```

Tried this but couldn't get this to work.

```
TextWriter x = File.OpenWrite ("my.csv", ....);

x.WriteLine("Column1,Column2"); // header
x.WriteLine(coups.Cells[0].Text + "," + coups.Cells[1].Text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,25,63,64,65,66,67'
html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'screener-content'})

light_rows = main_div.find_all('tr', class_="table-light-row-cp")
dark_rows = main_div.find_all('tr', class_="table-dark-row-cp")

data = []
for rows_set in (light_rows, dark_rows):
    for row in rows_set:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            val = cell.a.get_text()
            row_data.append(val)
        data.append(row_data)

#   sort rows to maintain original order
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(data).to_csv("AAA.csv", header=False)
```

Few things here:

1. I used "table-[light|dark]-row-cp" becouse all rows of intrest had one of those classes (and no other rows had them)
2. There are two sepearate parts: one is fetching data in correct structure, other - writing CSV file.
3. I used pandas CSV writer, because I'm familiar with it, but when you have rectangular data (named "data" here) you may use any other CSV writer
4. You should never name variables with reserved names, like 'sub' or 'link' : )

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built-in [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)?